# Sum up delivered companies for every customer(ID)

Tags: sql-server

I'm back in action ;) This time I have a pretty heavy task (I think).

Here's what I got:

```
|customerID ||company  |compdel |Street  |Code |Date 1     |Date 2     |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|1          ||Example1 |DELExam1|ABC Rd.1|4025 |01.01.2015 |01.08.2015 |
|1          ||Example1 |DELExam1|ABC Rd.1|4025 |13.04.2015 |01.12.2015 |
|1          ||Example1 |DELExam2|DEL St.1|0212 |13.03.2015 |09.07.2015 |
|1          ||Example1 |DELExam3|REF Wy.1|9875 |26.05.2015 |16.09.2015 |
|2          ||Example2 |DELExam4|REG St.1|6754 |21.02.2015 |16.05.2015 |
|2          ||Example2 |DELExam5|HIO Wy.1|9999 |01.03.2015 |06.08.2015 |
|2          ||Example2 |DELExam5|HIO Wy.1|9999 |01.01.2015 |06.02.2015 |
```

I want to show for every customerID every delivered company (compdel) summed in one line with the earliest date in Date 1 and the newest Date in Date 2. To make it easier to understand, I want this result:

```
|customerID ||company  |compdel |Street  |Code |Date 1     |Date 2     |
+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|1          ||Example1 |DELExam1|ABC Rd.1|4025 |01.01.2015 |01.12.2015 |
|1          ||Example1 |DELExam2|DEL St.1|0212 |13.03.2015 |09.07.2015 |
|1          ||Example1 |DELExam3|REF Wy.1|9875 |26.05.2015 |16.09.2015 |
|2          ||Example2 |DELExam4|REG St.1|6754 |21.02.2015 |16.05.2015 |
|2          ||Example2 |DELExam5|HIO Wy.1|9999 |01.01.2015 |06.08.2015 |
```

I tried it already with this select-Statement but it won´t work: I know, that this can only be a part of the answer....

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         customerID, company, compdel, Street, Code, Date 1, Date 2, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY compdel ORDER BY customerID) rn
     FROM 
         table 1) as Y
WHERE 
    rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with distinct values (customerId, company etc.) and `MIN` and `MAX` for dates

```
SELECT CustomerId
    , Company
    , CompDel
    , Street
    , Code
    , MIN(Date1) As EarliestDate1
    , MAX(Date2) AS NewestDate2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CustomerId, Company, CompDel, Street, Code
```